# Why can I take $0\le \alpha +tp^i \le p^i -1$ in the following lemma concerning a p-adic approximation

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, p-adic-number-theory

The following lemma is from Neal Koblitz - p-adic Numbers, p-adic Analysis, and Zeta-Functions-Springer (1996).

[image]

Can someone please explain the last part? why does adding a multiple of $p^i$ to the integer $\alpha$ yield an integer between $0$ and $p^i-1$?
So , that means that using the fact that $|.|_p$ is a non-Archimedean norm : $|\alpha +tp^i-x|_p\le max(|x-\alpha|_p,|tp^i|_p)\le p^{-i} $ because it was proved that $|x-\alpha|_p\le 1/p^i$ and $|tp^{i}|_p = 1/p^i$. But I don't know how to conclude from this that  $0\le \alpha +tp^i \le p^i -1$ nor what  the initial interval for $\alpha$ was. Any idea?

Comment: Since $\alpha$ is an integer, you can imagine just the regular number line from elementary school, and adding or subtracting $p^i$ will translate it left or right until you get it into the interval between $0$ and $p^i$.

Comment: @Mersosity, thanks it makes sense. I just corrected a typo, it was between $0$ and $p^i-1$, but I get the idea